# How do I inherit Scaladoc from Scala's standard library?

Tags: scala, inheritance, documentation, sbt

If I understand correctly, the Scaladoc of a method should automatically inherit the Scaladoc of the parent method it overrides. This seems to hold true for a local set of classes, but not when extending from Scala's standard library (and presumably any external dependency?).

```
class LocalParent {
  /**
   * some documentation
   */
  def foo = ???
}

class DocumentedChild extends LocalParent

class UndocumentedChild extends Iterator[Int] {
   def hasNext = ???
   def next = ???
}
```

Is there a way to inherit the Scaladoc? Or am I doing something wrong?

Also, I'm using `sbt doc`, so not `scaladoc` directly.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation wherein they specify how to handle importing the docs from external dependencies: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Howto/scaladoc.html (they say `autoAPIMappings := true` and `apiURL := Some(url("http://example.org/api/"))`.)

Comment: Same as Randall's answer. This seems to only hyperlink to the original documentation, but it does not pull scaladoc through at the method level.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I use (SBT 0.13):

```
scalacOptions in (Compile, doc) ++=
  Seq("-diagrams",
      "-diagrams-max-classes",
      "20",
      "-external-urls:java=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/," +
      "scala=http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/")
```

**Addendum 1:**

To address the issue of subclassing standard library classes while overriding methods and wanting the overridden method's documentation comment, members can be commented with the inherit documentation tag:

```
/** @inheritdoc */
override def foo(bar: String): Int = bar.length
```

**Addendum 2:**

The more modern form of this functionality is documented on [this SBT 0.13 documentation page](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Howto/scaladoc.html).

Comment: What should it be? We're not doing anything Java 7-specific here and we have a mix of JVMs in use…

Comment: I try to use the Javadoc for the oldest Java that I want to support so I don't accidentally use new features.

Comment: This seems to only hyperlink classes. It doesn't address documentation at the method level. Or at least I can't get it to work on my machine.

Comment: @MarkCanlas: I'm not entirely clear what you mean by "address documentation at the method level." Are you overriding standard library methods? If so, you can always use `/** @inheritdoc */`.

Comment: We're not on the same page or I'm doing something wrong. I get `The comment for method next contains @inheritdoc, but no parent comment is available to inherit from.`. If you `sbt doc` the code that I wrote above with whatever settings, do you see the Scaladoc for each method inherited from Iterator?

Comment: I'd take it for what it says. There's no documentation comment to inherit. But it's surely possible that `@inheritdoc` does not traverse a `-external-urls` directive

Comment: @som-snytt: I really did mean what I said: We're not doing anything Java 7-specific and we really do have a mixture of JVM 6 and JVM 7 in our world. There is no Java / JVM 8 anything here. After all it's barely released and offers nothing to a Scala shop…

Comment: Note `-external-urls` is deprecated in 2.10, absent in 2.11.

Comment: It will do links `[[scala.Function1]]` only.  It actually emits the inheritdoc error in the doc output: `I am a scala.Function1. <invalid inheritdoc annotation>`.

Comment: Looks like inheritdoc is handled by compiler, not scaladoc operating on artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier nowadays. Simply add

```
autoAPIMappings := true
```

to your SBT settings. (`build.sbt` or `project/Build.scala`)

Tested with SBT version 0.13.5 and Scala 2.11.7, but it should work all the way back to 2.10.2, per the [SBT documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Scaladoc.html)

That should work for any managed dependencies that specify where their documentation lives. If it's not working for some dependencies, see the [other options](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Scaladoc.html).