# Inherit Scala standard classes documentation in Scaladoc

Tags: scala, scaladoc

This should be a easy question but I just can't find a clear answer.

I'm trying to create a Scaladoc for my project. Let's say I have a class such as:

```
/**
* This is an example
*/
object foo extends Enumeration {
    ...
}
```

Then I generate a Scaladoc and, in my Scaladoc document, I want the word `Enumeration` to have a link to the current `scala.Enumeration` class and to inherit all the documentation from the methods taken from `scala.Enumeration`.

Is it possible to do that? If so, how can I do it? I've seen this post ([How do I inherit Scaladoc from Scala's standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765955/how-do-i-inherit-scaladoc-from-scalas-standard-library)), but the method they used to solve the problem is no longer possible. They talk about a solution in Maven that doesn't work anymore (was deprecated and eliminated long ago) and some other solutions that force me to use `sbt` instead of `Maven`

I'm trying to generate the documentation using `Maven` (not `sbt`), so I'm not sure if that could turn to be a problem too...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I inherit Scaladoc from Scala's standard library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765955/how-do-i-inherit-scaladoc-from-scalas-standard-library)

Comment: I don't think so, I checked it before writing this message.
 That question refers to `sbt` variables to solve the problem, something I can't do with `Maven`. There is a solution that could work for `Maven`...but its use was deprecated and eliminated, so I can't use it either.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify how your *question* is different rather than how the question that has no accepted answers is lacking a good answer. It seems to me like a good answer to either question would also be a good answer to the other, or trivially translate to one.